# When is .ss domain going to be available?

Tags: domains, domain-registrar, top-level-domains, cctld

The [Wikipedia article for the .ss ccTLD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.ss) states:

> **.ss** is the designated country code top-level domain (ccTLD) for South Sudan in the Domain Name System of the Internet. It is derived from the ISO 3166-1 alpha-2 code for South Sudan, which is SS.
>
> According to CIO East Africa, the TLD was allocated on 10 August 2011 following the country's declaration of independence from Sudan. The TLD was registered on 31 August 2011; as of 8 December 2015, it is not in the DNS root zone and thus not operational.
>
> Before .ss was successfully registered, the country's Undersecretary for Telecommunications had initially been concerned about the ccTLD request's possible rejection due to SS also being an abbreviation for Schutzstaffel, the paramilitary force of Nazi Germany.
>
> Before the independence of South Sudan, the applicable domain was .sd, Sudan's top-level Internet domain.

So my question is this:

When is .ss domain going to be available for all mortals, and how to stop domain names to be (for example) **jewish-community.ss** or similar unappropriate or maybe insulting names?

Also, how is it even possible that no one didn't stop this?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about **[webmastering as defined in the FAQ](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)**.

Comment: This is a topic better suited for [chat]

Comment: Hey John, this is domain question? It's not off topic, it's legit question about South Sudan's top level domain.

Comment: When it will be available and how to deal with discrimination, besides being two different issues, are not on-topic for this website.Not everything related to domains is on-topic examples being where, how, and when to register a domain.

Comment: So, should I rephrase my question then and ask about discrimination and then ask another one about availability?

Comment: As of right now both questions would be off-topic here so i don't think this will solve your problem.

Comment: It may be off-topic, but I liked it and up-voted it for thoughtfulness which in my book is a criteria for a user I like. Cheers!!

Comment: It's an interesting question that draws attention to the importance of cultural sensitivity on a global scale...but it doesn't appear answerable due to its [lack of sponsorship](http://www.iana.org/domains/root/db/ss.html) almost five years later, and the second part as John indicated would invite an [opinion-based discussion](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask), which is considered off-topic for Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: I opened this question on meta so we can do a discussion. :*